# How to create diurnal profiles by month with pandas and matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm creating a set of graphs that will show diurnal profiles computed by month, from pandas dataframe.

I have a pandas dataframe, with multiple columns and thousands of rows.

```
                      gh  flg_gh   dh  flg_dh  ...      ap  flg_ap  GHIc DNIc
datetime                                       ...                           
2014-02-21 22:07:30  0.0       1  0.0       1  ...  1015.0    None   0.0  0.0
2014-02-21 22:12:30  0.0       1  0.0       1  ...  1015.0    None   0.0  0.0
2014-02-21 22:17:30  0.0       1  0.0       1  ...  1015.0    None   0.0  0.0
2014-02-21 22:22:30  0.0       1  0.0       1  ...  1015.0    None   0.0  0.0
2014-02-21 22:27:30  0.0       1  0.0       1  ...  1015.0    None   0.0  0.0
```

Right now, I am able to make a plot, but it is slow. Is there any faster way to get the result?

Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import dates as d
import datetime as dt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12,6))

dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))

for month in dataframe['Month'].unique():
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]

    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()

    ax.plot(df.index, df['gh']['mean'], linewidth=2.0, label = month)

ax.legend()

ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
plt.show()
```

[diurnal profiles by month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSA6m.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `df.groupby('Time').mean()` instead of `df.groupby('Time').describe()`, if you are only interested in plotting the mean. [`pandas.DataFrame.describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) will calculate a bunch of other statistics that it looks like you are not using.

Also, one nice pandas feature is that a `DateTimeIndex` has attributes like the month or time baked in, so instead of

```
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
```

you can simply

```
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.month
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.time
```

See the documentation for [`DateTimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) to see the other attributes.

Comment: Thanks! Using `.mean()` instead of `.describe()`  is way to go. It sped up from 41 seconds to 0.15 seconds!